# how to generate initial vector for counter mode of encryption

Tags: aes

i am implementing CTR mode of encryption using AES. i want know how to generate initial vectors(counter blocks) for this mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should generate random IV, and after that increment it with each new block, like 16-byte integer.
Also, as far as I remember, some specifications use zero IV for CTR mode.